# Request: Restriction to ask a new question for new users

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

There are some users who sign up for puzzling but they just ask a question (most probably from ongoing contest, or for spams, or unrelated questions to puzzling etc) and leave the page. Therefore I believe to ask a question in Puzzling, there has to be some limitations such as;

- At least 100+ reputations
- At least 2 weeks to pass after registration

to ask a new question... This limitation is just an example, it could be something else to prevent such acts in my opinion. I don't know, maybe just 100+ reputation which could be gained by answering and voting questions/answers etc.

Comment: Do you realize that unregistered users (those with only-cookie accounts) can post? Stack Exchange is reluctant to even turn that off; they're not going to require extra burdens on registered users. Finally: my [first puzzle here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98568/puzzling-at-home-order) was posted on my first day, **after I had lurked for a while to make sure it would be acceptable** - it's not my best puzzle but it's a good one. New users are not uniformly bad.

Comment: Voting questions to earn rep is too overpowered, people can get from 15 to 25k rep in no time. There are some users who participate actively in the site who have been here from 2104 and have not gotten to 25k rep yet.

Comment: @user71981 Time travelers who've come to experience 2020 for educational purposes?

Comment: @entioneveryone I meant 2014 not 2104

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see where this request is coming from, but I don't think this is a good idea, at least not the right execution.

I've listed the questions with First Posts reviews (so they must have been posted by a user without reputation, except possibly for the association bonus and/or a few suggested edits), created by a user less than 14 days old. *We would possibly miss those* if your feature request would be implemented:

[image]

([source, with clickable links to questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/1347639))

Comment: this doesnt have to be the way as I said, could be something else, I dont know :)

Answer (score 1):

I do understand you, but **no**, I do **not** agree with you. I do agree with the line,

> There are some users who sign up for puzzling but they just ask a question (most probably from ongoing contest, or for spams, or unrelated questions to puzzling etc)

but that's only for **some** users, as you said. Take [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105009) for example(this is a 10k rep link). Some other users might not ask these types of questions. If you do want a restriction, I'd probably suggest:

> Read some pages on the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) so that they know more about the site and what type of questions not to ask.

before they ask a question. 100 reputation before a question can be asked is a little too much for new users. At least 2 weeks to pass after registration is also a bit too much. With these restrictions, some users would be quite frustrated and they would leave the site and not ask the question that they wanted to ask which could be very well-received, getting a lot of views and a lot of upvotes by the first day. Also, gaining reputation by voting on questions/answers is too overpowered, even if it is just 1 per post, as users with 15 reputation - a very small amount - can earn reputation just by clicking on a button and get 200 reputation(the cap) a day every day and they would easily be able to get to 25,000 reputation(where you earn your last privilege) in no time just by clicking on buttons every day, without posting a **single** thing. People would eventually start abusing this by making hard-to-detect scripts to vote posts, getting them from 15 to 25k reputation in no time. Thank you.